# Device to Cloud Messaging Azure IOT Hub

Tags: asp.net, azure, routes, message, iot

I would like to route the IOT hub device to cloud messages to the asp.net core web app hosted as azure AppService. I am not sure whether it is possible. If yes, could you please provide the necessary instructions to achieve the same.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly then Iot Hub messages can be routed to different endpoint like these

Built-in-endpoint 
Blob storage 
Event Hubs 
Service Bus Queues 
Service Bus Topics

Web app can then read messages from any of above endpoints.
more info here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c